# How to manually open Woocommerce mini cart block drawer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, wordpress, woocommerce

The woocommerce **MiniCartBlock** has this to open the drawer in `plugins\woocommerce\packages\woocommerce-blocks\assets\js\blocks\mini-cart\block.tsx 122`

```
const openMiniCart = () => {
    if ( addToCartBehaviour === 'open_drawer' ) {
        setSkipSlideIn( false );
        setIsOpen( true );
    }
};
```

It also has this...

```
document.body.addEventListener(
    'wc-blocks_added_to_cart',
     openMiniCart
);
```

So my question is how do i fire this event `'wc-blocks_added_to_cart'` or any other method so that the drawer opens. I tried this to  fire the event but no luck -> `jQuery( document.body ).trigger( 'wc-blocks_added_to_cart' );`

Comment: You can actually trigger a click event on the mini cart drawer button.

Comment: How is that? Do you have any example? i tried but working any of mine!

Comment: generally button class should be `.wc-block-mini-cart__button` you can run a jQuery code like this `jQuery('.wc-block-mini-cart__button').trigger('click');` it will trigger the button click and drawer will open.

Comment: Thanks will try that... but it might not work on iOS devices as in iOS devices you can't trigger user interactions actually.